# Android NDK can't find JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs after update from r6 to r7

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I've updated my NDK version from r6 to r7. After that I get this error when compiling one of my native files:

> error: 'JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs' was not declared in this scope

I am building my project for the API level 8 (Android 2.2). I've examined the

> (MY_NDK_PATH_R6)/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h

where the `GetCreatedJavaVMs` is declared and the file `jni.h` is actually a symlink to

> (MY_NDK_PATH_R6)/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h

Then I checked the

> (MY_NDK_PATH_R7)/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h

and it is actually a file, and not a symlink.

I'm building my project using Eclipse and the only thing I've specified in preferences is path to the `ndk-build`.

EDIT: OK, it's clear now why GetCreatedJavaVMs could not be found:

```
/*
 * VM initialization functions.
 *
 * Note these are the only symbols exported for JNI by the VM.
 */
#if 0  /* In practice, these are not exported by the NDK so don't declare them */
jint JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(void*);
jint JNI_CreateJavaVM(JavaVM**, JNIEnv**, void*);
jint JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(JavaVM**, jsize, jsize*);
#endif
```

But how should I get the VM in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the solution.
You just need to implement the JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) function. JVM is an argument.
Probably this is better way of getting the JVM.

Comment: That's an excellent observation. I've discovered it pays well to save it in a static variable and re-use it whenever required.